# How to disable PageUp/PageDown in ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, .net-2.0

instead of jumping to the beginnng/end of the ListView, I would like to perform some other operation. So I would like to disable jumping through the ListView with PageUp/PageDown and perform some other operation.

I thought I could do sth. like

```
ListView.PreviewKeyDown
```

and do a

```
e.Handled = true,
```

but it is only possible to set

```
e.Handled = true
```

in

```
ListView.KeyUp.
```

But when trying to catch PageUp/PageDown in

```
ListView.Keyup,
```

the selection has already jumped to the beginning or end.

So how can I disable jumping to the beginning/end and perform instead an other operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown.aspx) instead.

However, I have to advice against changing something basic like this. Users expect a certain thing when pressing page up / down inside a list view. Overriding this behavior makes it harder for your users to use your application.